# Can DFS both do a topological sort on a graph *AND* detect if a graph has a cycle at the same time?

Tags: depth-first-search, schedule, topological-sort

I was doing a question on leetcode regarding scheduling courses ([https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule/description/#*=*](https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule/description/#_=_))

but I seem to be really confusing myself for some reason. I believe that this problem is equivalent to determining whether its representation as a graph has a topological sorting. But only directed acyclic graphs can have a topological sorting - so we'd either have to check beforehand if it has a cycle, or check if it has a cycle while searching through it and performing the topological sort.

One of the solutions posted that uses DFS is as follows:

```
public class Solution {
        public boolean canFinish(int numCourses, int[][] prerequisites) {
            ArrayList[] graph = new ArrayList[numCourses];
            for(int i=0;i<numCourses;i++)
                graph[i] = new ArrayList();

            boolean[] visited = new boolean[numCourses];
            for(int i=0; i<prerequisites.length;i++){
                graph[prerequisites[i][1]].add(prerequisites[i][0]);
            }

            for(int i=0; i<numCourses; i++){
                if(!dfs(graph,visited,i))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private boolean dfs(ArrayList[] graph, boolean[] visited, int course){
            if(visited[course])
                return false;
            else
                visited[course] = true;;

            for(int i=0; i<graph[course].size();i++){
                if(!dfs(graph,visited,(int)graph[course].get(i)))
                    return false;
            }
            visited[course] = false;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

It looks like all its doing is checking if the the node (course) has been visited before - but isn't it possible that a node has been visited before but there not to be a cycle in the graph? How is this code checking that there is no cycle so that it knows it has a topological sorting?

Comment: Please note that [dfs] is not the right tag for this question. [breadth-first-search] is what you want

Comment: how so? you can definitely use dfs to solve this

Comment: Sorry, I meant [depth-first-search]. [dfs] tag is not for depth-first-search.